# How do I remove tfspreview from my TFS server list?

Tags: tfs

We have stopped using tfspreview, and are now on visualstudio.com. However, I keep getting strange errors when getting latest. First, I want to remove tfspreview from the server list. How do you do this? The 'remove' button is disabled.

[image: remove is disabled...]

Comment: You can't remove a server that you're connected to.  Might that be the problem?

Comment: After another reboot, I again selected 'disconnect' under the team menu. I was able to then remove it. Seems like the UI should be a little more helpful there.

Answer (score 4):

In visual studio, select the Team menu and disconnect from TFS server. Then navigate to the team explorer and click on "Select Team Projects". Once the window is open, click "Servers" button and select the server that you wish to remove. Since you are no longer connected to the TFS server, you can now click Remove.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TFS credential from the **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager** screen.